User Login data is not storing inside the mysql work bench
enter image description hereThe scenario is, when the user tries to sign up or register using a web browser. The user input credentials are working fine, in the browser but the case is, the user credentials are not save in the MySql workbecnh.
It was not showing, it only displays a null.
I'm expecting that the user credentials that was inputted in the sign up local host in web browser, is gonna store in the my sql workbench database
package com.example.appointmentreservation.model.dao;

import com.example.appointmentreservation.model.entity.User;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public static final String SELECT_ALL_USERS= "SELECT * FROM users";
    public static final String SELECT_USER_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    public static final String INSERT_USER = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)"
            ;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User User) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER);
            stmt.setString(1, User.getUsername());
            stmt.setString(2, User.getPassword());
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByID(int id) {
        User user01 = new User();
        try {
            Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_USER_BY_ID);
            stmt.setInt(1,id);
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();

            if (result.next()) {
                user01.setUsername(result.getString("username"));
                user01.setPassword(result.getString("password"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return user01;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        try {
            Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_ALL_USERS);
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                User user01 = new User();
                user01.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                user01.setUsername(result.getString("username"));
                user01.setPassword(result.getString("password"));
                users.add(user01);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return List.of();
    }

}


Are the username and password present on the User instance? --- A word of advice: do not store clear-text passwords. Never. Anywhere. The passwords should be hashed and salted.

What do you mean by "user credentials are not save in the MySql workbecnh."  MySQL Workbench is a MySQL client program.  Nothing is stored in that program.. the place data is stored is the database.  I assume that this is what you mean.  So are you sure you java code is accessing the same database that you look at via MySQL Workbench?  There is no evidence in the code you provide about which database (or schema) you are accessing.

To amplify Turing85 - don't EVER write your own password authentication code. Use a professionally-built library and keep it up to date. If the library doesn't have a new version fairly frequently, ditch it for another that is well-maintained.
